# If else condition after click button in Wixcode

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, velo

I am a beginner in using wix. Currently im doing the job application form. How to create a new text field after click "Add another vacancy" button? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a new element using Velo. What you need to do is add the element in the Editor and set it as hidden or collapsed. Then, using Velo, you can show or expand the element based on some condition.